# I am looking for a short story, "Hello My Name is God" might be the title

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I am looking for this short story that I read back in the early to mid 90s.  It was published (I think) in Fantasy and Science fiction.  The story was very short only 2-3 pages.  And the Punch line was

> Always spay and neuter your pets

Comment: http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=hello&type=Fiction+Titles - Nothing especially obvious here

Comment: I THINK I remember this... it's like a PSA from a creator to other creators using Earth as a demonstration, if it's the one I'm thinking of...

Comment: PSA from The Creator!!

Answer (score 8):

It's a *very* short story, and the aforementioned punchline isn't the surprise ending. It more like serves as the source of the other punchline at the end.

It's ["Do Unto Others" by Kelvin Throop](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?286061).

Looks like it was published only once, in the 2004 Analog. (I know you said early to mid 90s, but other than that and not remembering the anthology it's a match.)

It's so short it's almost over while you're still wondering what is happening. Not much time spent explaining -- just... a group discussion going on before you arrived.

> "I got the idea from a postage stamp," God said, which did little to reassure the assembled
> and assorted clerics. Like most attendees at professional conferences, He wore a neat plastic
> badge that said, "Hi! My name is God," though exactly what it said His name was depended on
> who was reading it.
>
> But that was minor compared to the issue at hand. "A postage stamp?" an Episcopalian
> echoed incredulously. "What could a postage stamp have to do with this? You said you gathered
> us here because -- "

Different people start speaking up about what is bothering them. Their livestock are "dying off" (God replies that everyone dies off -- eventually).
And many humans are sterile.

God tells them the average birthrates, that after our overpopulation, the population now is just under replacement.

> “That sounds pretty sustainable to Me."

They're all "You said be fruitful and multiply!" and God says that that was then, when there were so few of you that you might not have made it. And now you're out of control destroying the planet, and haven't learned any self-control.

God describes the postage stamps with cute kittens and puppies with the message "Save lives. Neuter or spay."

And he figured that if a few people cared enough about animals to help control their population, and some people understood the platitude about "Do unto others", then he figured he could do the same for humans.

> "I realized that you, too, had an over-breeding problem and hadn't learned to take care of it yourselves. So I did it for you."